# Removing "NOT IN" clause and optimising a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, sql-insert

We have a `group` and `user permission` table as follows :

```
Group (group_id,name)
01 | G1
02 | G2
03 | G3
04 | G4
```

---

```
UserPermission (userid,group_id,active)
User1 | 01 | 1
User1 | 02 | 1
User2 | 01 | 1
User2 | 02 | 1
User2 | 03 | 1
User2 | 04 | 1
..
UserN | xx | 1
```

---

Each *User* has permission to a *Group*.
But some of the permissions for some users are missing in UserPermission table.

*The problem is to insert those missing group permission entries for all users present in the  `UserPermission` table .*

So the query i came up with is 
(crude )

```
 insert into UserPermission 
         select distinct userid, '03', 1 from UserPermission  
         where userid not in (
               select userid from UserPermission where group_id = '03'
         )
```

This was for insert permissions missing for users for `Group 03` ..
similar for other groups .

Is there a better way to write the above query. How can it be optimised?

Comment: How many records are you talking here? Are you noticing a performance issue or are you just asking in general?

Comment: in general..But there are about ~30 groups and about 7K-8K users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my solution, I get the cartesian product from table `Group` and `UserPermission` (*unique userID only*). The product of the two table is then join back on table `UserPermission` using `LEFT JOIN` provided that it match on two columns: `Group_ID` and `userID`. Any records that will not satisfy the condition will have `NULL` values on the columns for `UserPermission`. And these values are the missing values in the `UserPermission` table.

This will also **populate all missing permission for all users**.

```
INSERT INTO UserPermission(userID, group_ID, active)
SELECT  b.userID, a.Group_ID, 1
FROM    [Group] a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT userID FROM UserPermission) b
        LEFT JOIN UserPermission c
            ON a.Group_ID = c.Group_ID AND
                b.userID = c.UserID
WHERE   c.Group_ID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8755/1)

---

But if you want to insert only specific `Group_ID`, then you need extra condition.

```
INSERT INTO UserPermission(userID, group_ID, active)
SELECT  b.userID, a.Group_ID, 1
FROM    [Group] a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT userID FROM UserPermission) b
        LEFT JOIN UserPermission c
            ON a.Group_ID = c.Group_ID AND
                b.userID = c.UserID
WHERE   c.Group_ID IS NULL AND
        a.Group_ID = 3
        -- or change it to IN clause
        -- if you have more Group_ID to include
        -- a.Group_ID IN (3,4)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0752/1)

Comment: generic solution was nice.. no hardcoding required..nice!

Comment: @Amitd I added an update if you want to hard code values. `:)`

Comment: Don't think the query will change if i wanted to make it user specific? 4th line will have the change i guess?

Comment: btw how does the cross join help in the above query??

Comment: this query worked perfectly for me.. thx a lot :) accepted as answer now

Answer (score 1):

Not exists usually performs better than not in.

```
insert into UserPermission
select disinct userid, '03', 1
from UserPermission
where not exists 
(select *
from UserPermission
where group_id = '03')
```

Another way is to use "in" instead of "not in"

```
insert into UserPermission
select disinct userid, '03', 1
from UserPermission
where user_id in 
(select user_id from UserPermission
except 
select user_id from UserPermission
where group_id = '03')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
 with toinsert as (
    select userid, '03' as UserPermission
    from UserPermission up
    group by userId
    having sum9case when userPermission = '03' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
 )
 insert into UpserPermission
    select userid, UserPermission
    from toinsert;
```

I've broken up the insert list into a CTE.  You can also do this just as a subquery:

```
insert into UserPermission
    select userid, '03'
    from UserPermission
    group by userid
    having sum(case when userpermission = '03' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: can this query be made more generic?

Comment: @Amitd . . . Absolutely.  The advantage to using the `group by` with `having` clause for "set-within-set" questions is that all the conditions go in the `having` clause.  This allows you to generalize it pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution would be to use the new MERGE statement. In my experience, MERGE performs extremely well.

```
merge UserPermission target
using (
    -- Assuming u.userid and g.group_id are unique in their tables
    select u.userid, g.group_id
    from [User] u
    cross join [Group] g
) source on source.userid = target.userid and source.group_id = target.group_id
when not matched then
    insert (userid, group_id, active)
    values (source.userid, source.group_id, 1);
```